# Why is JQuery not working in my MVC 4 application after Firefox Update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox

I have been writing an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS.  I had it working perfectly in an older version of Firefox and in IE 11.  It still works great in IE 11, but after I updated FF to 35.0.1, My script is not working.  How do I get my script to work in the newest version of Firefox?

My _Layout view contians the following script:

```
 ......
 @Scripts.Render("~bundles/jquery")
 <script>
      $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
      type: 'post',
      cache: 'false,
      async: 'true',
      data: '{}',
      success: function(result){
      $('#progress').html(result);
           } 
      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
           function RefreshPartial(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                     loadPartialView();
                    RefreshPartial();
                }, 3000);
           }
      RefreshPartial();
      }); 
 </script>
 @RenderSection("scripts", required:  false)
 </body>
 ......
```

In Firefox/Fox It hits the

```
 "$(document).ready(function ()  {"
```

line then jumps to the bottom of the script

```
 });
```

before going to the Jquery.  It never comes back to my inline JS.  It throws the following exception:  "SyntaxError:  An Invalid or illegal string was specified" at the "if" statment below:

```
 3093     for ( ; list && firingIndex < firingLength; firingIndex++ ) {
 3094          if ( list[ firingIndex ].apply{ data[  ], data[ 1 ] ) == false && options.stopOnFalse )  {
                    memory = false;
                    break;
               }
          }
```

It loops through the for statment several times and then throws an error at the same if statement:  "TypeError:  Constructor Document requires 'new'".
It never runs my inline script so my partial view is never loaded.  Again, this only happens in the newest version of FF.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: If you comment out the Ajax call, does the error go away? If you comment out the code in the document ready, does the code go away? You need to narrow down the area where it is being triggered.

Comment: It  never gets up to that function containing the AJAX call. There seems to be a syntax error at the document ready function according to Firebug.

Comment: It is giving a syntax error at the document ready function line:  "An invalid or illegal string was specified."

Comment: wow, someone voted my question down.  As if they new the answer.  I didn't ask until after trouble shooting for quite some time.  Trolls..  SMH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 35.0.1 does not like th e long version of:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

My code works using the shorthand version:

```
 $(function()  {
```

I don't know why, but it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

I see not reason why it should not work... Have you try doing a simple jquery alert? does it work? remove the ajax call and do the alert if you get the alert to work, then your jquery is working. otherwise you might not been linking jquery properly. if the alert works try a simple hit or miss ajax call.

```
    $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Edit: there is not reason why FF would not work with `$(document).ready(function(){});`
I am currently using it for a web service and it works just fine with: safari, chrome, FF and IE plus four or five more mobile browsers.